# How do I name an object in python by concatenating two strings?

Tags: python, concatenation, naming

I want to name an object "Nov2019" and I am trying the following:

```
Month = "Nov"
Year = "2019"
Year + Month = [100, 90, 80]
```

I want to have a list containing three integers which is named "Nov2019" by concatenation.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to wrap `Year + Month` with `locals()`:

```
Month = "Nov"
Year = "2019"
locals()[Year + Month] = [100, 90, 80]

print(Nov2019)
```

Output:

```
[100, 90, 80]
```

*Note: Using `locals()`, `vars()`, `globals()`, `eval()`, `exec()`, etc. are all bad practices. 
Best to go with a `dict`.*

Answer (score 4):

It is possible if you put the variable inside a dictionary:

```
mydict = {}
Month = "Nov"
Year = "2019"
mydict[Year + Month] = [100, 90, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

`locals()[f"{Month}{Year}"] = [100, 90, 80]`

or

`globals()[f"{Month}{Year}"] = [100, 90, 80]`

But a dictionary would be superior as the other answer mentions

Also, if you want your variable name/key to be "Nov2019", you should do Month + Year, not Year + Month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` method. A variable name can't start by a number, so a way to do that is invert the Month with Year. You can either put in a dictionary, but this approach is more aproximate to your question.

```
Month = "Nov"
Year = "2019"
exec(Month + Year + '= [100, 90, 80]')
print(Nov2019)
#[100,90,80]
```